# Bad Request - Invalid Hostname IIS when accessed using domain name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I am fairly newbie to .Net and IIS.

I have developed an application using C#, ASP.NET webforms. The application is running on Windows server 2012 R2.

I can access the application using `http://localhost:35419/.`

But when I try to access the application using machine name like `http://machine_name.domain.com:35419`, I get the `"Bad Request - Invalid Hostname IIS HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid."` error.

I have gone through many posts on stack overflow and other forums to figure out that I need to add the website on IIS manager and edit the bindings for the site. But even then its throwing out the same error.

Could some one guide me on how to correct this problem ?

Comment: if this is iis express can only be local.

Comment: @DanielA.White  Yes . the website is running on IIS express . how to get around that ?

Comment: you must use the real iis.

Comment: @DanielA.White I just installed visual studio ultimate version. I did not install iis separately. Do I need to change some thing to use real IIS . Could you please guide me ?

Comment: that question is better suited for [sf]. its part of windows, not visual studio

Comment: You don't need to use IIS real, you can stay with express and install our extension 'Conveyor' that allows you to access it remotely https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti